# phpmyadmin wont import funstuff.sql.zip file

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, mamp

I am trying to import a database.sql.zip to phpmyadmin
because its to massive to import unzipped.

Im using Mamp.

But when I try to import the database, using the utf8 which is the correct one.

when I press go PHPMYADMIN shows me this

[image: White page]

Comment: What on earth is funstuff.sql.zip?

Comment: I what I was trying to write was a database dump thats zipped.

Comment: Which phpMyAdmin version?

Answer (score 2):

Doh,

I figured out why, its was the zip file that was giving problems, when you use another format for example `gzip`, everything goes smooth :)

Answer (score 0):

1. login to your mysql shell "mysql -u root"
2. navigate to the db "use yourDbName"
3. run this "source /path/to/that/file.sql"